# Install OpenCV on Windows : "dll Load failed"

Tags: python, windows, opencv, dll

I had some trouble installing OpenCV on Windows, and I wanted to share a solution that worked for me as I didn't find good ones online. Actually there are three ways to install OpenCV 4 on windows :

1. Install via opencv-python : just `pip install opencv-python`
2. Install with the binary file (unofficial) : you can look at the tutorial [here](https://pysource.com/2019/03/15/how-to-install-python-3-and-opencv-4-on-windows/)
3. Install via the pre-built libraries. I tried to build OpenCV by myself using CMake but this took too much time and I faced the problem of "DLL Load Failed". So here is how I managed to get this done. First, download the latest libraries from the official documentation of OpenCV on sourceforge [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html). 
   Execute the .exe downloaded and select a directory of your choice as this will be the folder where OpenCV will be saved at the end. 
   Then, go to the environment variables (Control panel -> System and security -> System -> Advanced system parameters -> Environment variables) and add a new variable named "OPENCV_DIR" in the system variables section. In the value section put : `<path_to_your_OpenCV_directory>\Build\x64\vc14` and click on "OK". 
   Now, look for a variable named "PYTHONPATH" in the system variables section and click on "modify". If you don't find it, just create it. To the value section, add `<path_to_your_OpenCV_directory>\build\\python`

This way, OpenCV is installed on my computer and I have the directory of OpenCV with all the files needed that I couldn't find by doing just `pip install opencv-python`.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Python OpenCV can be easily installed by running command on Anaconda. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv